# Is this a correct control input for this nonlinear system

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Take a look at this system
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= \cos x_2 + (x_2+1)x_3 \tag{1}\\
\dot{x}_2 &= x^3_1+x_3 \tag{2}\\
\dot{x}_3 &= x^2_1+u \tag{3}\\
y&=x_1 \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
The objective is to design tracking reference signal $y_d(t)$. Since there is no direct relation between $y$ and $u$, we need to ascertain this by taking the derivative of Eq(4) twice, hence:
$$
\ddot{y} = (x_2+1)u + (x^3_1+x_3)(x_3-\sin x_2) + (x_2+1)x^2_1 \tag{5}
$$
Designing the input $u$ to explicitly cancel the linearities, we get
$$
u = \frac{1}{x_2+1}\Big(v-(x^3_1+x_3)(x_3-\sin x_2) + (x_2+1)x^2_1\Big) \tag{6}
$$
Substituting Eq(6) in Eq(5), we 
$$
\ddot{y} = v
$$

where 
$$
v = y_d -k_1e -k_2\dot{e} \tag{7}
$$ 
and $e=y-y_d$ which yields

$$
\ddot{e} + k_2\dot{e} + k_1e = 0 \tag{8}
$$
This is what has been shown in the book but I'm expecting an error in this equation in Eq(7) which I believe should be 
$$
v = \ddot{y}_d -k_1e -k_2\dot{e} 
$$ 
In order to get Eq(8). Is this a printed error? The book has no errata list. [Block Backstepping Design of Nonlinear State Feedback Control Law for Underactuated Mechanical Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789811019555)

[image]

I've simulated the system based on my correction to Eq(7) and I got this results. It seems to me this is a horrible printed mistake.

[image]

Comment: You are definitely correct. Since it is a relatively new book it could be no one else has spotted yet.